# Selenium script cannot launch Firefox or Chrome, but IE working?

Tags: c#, firefox, google-chrome, selenium, nunit

I am using Visual Studio 2008, and NUnit 2.4.7.

I am trying to run a script in IE, Firefox version 5, and Chrome.  It is working in IE, but in Firefox and Chrome it is throwing the same error.

Error In server :"preparing Firefox launching........"

It remains in the same state until I stop the server.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a bit of code so we might better be able to determine what is causing the problem?

Comment: Also, I thought selenium RC (the thing that launches the browser) was a separate component.  Do you know if you are running that and if so what version?  And what Selenium version?  If you can get answers for these, please edit the question and add them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever had a test run in Firefox and Chrome? If not, it's possible that you just need to add Environment Path Variables for Firefox and Chrome so that Selenium Server can find the other browsers perhaps?

If this is the case, this link will show you where to do it. http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/05/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7/

You should see the IE one in there already.